# How do we get Yaml Array object size

Tags: yaml

I am trying to get the size of the object array in Yaml. is there any method for finding the size or length of array in yaml. I need evaluate last object from the array of objects.

Comment: Hello Naveen, Welcome to StackOverflow. YAML is a data serialization format like XML or JSON. To obtain the length of an array in YAML you would need a YAML parser. Please also share using which tool or language are you processing your YAML? Only after having this detail, someone would be able to answer your query.

Comment: We are writing test cases in yamls and validating them using the rules mentioned in yaml files. These tests are run using Java.
Later when digged into the framework found that for matcher we are using hamcrest Matcher API.

Yaml rule is as follows:  
rules:
  - expression: 'array[0].type'
    matcher : 'equalToIgnoringCase'
    comparableValue: 'array'

Answer (score 1):

**YAML cannot do it**. YAML is just a "data" format, like XML, JSON or even CSV, there is no logic inside.

See comment of https://stackoverflow.com/users/363075/tarun above on your question.

So you need a "parser" or a "reader" application which will read the YAML file and the you can use something like `array.Length` or `array.Count`, this depend on your programming language.